# Script in ~/.bashrc works when manually executed, but not otherwise

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, bashrc, source

This is pretty strange.
So I developed this thing called `SahibLib` and it's basically a script that you source that sources a bunch of other scripts.

Its directory tree looks like this:

```
/home
    |- /home/myuser
       |- /home/myuser/sahiblib
          |- sahibload <- executed in ~/.bashrc
          |- sahiblib <- executed by sahibload
          |- modules
             |- core.sls <- problem file
             |- example.sls <- problem file
```

What SahibLib is **supposed** to do is source the `.sls` files. It doesn't do that though.

It outputs the correct message ("[SUCCESS] Thank you and goodbye."), but the actual files aren't sourced.

```
myuser@mypc:~$ slhelp
Invalid command.
```

Strangely, when I source the file manually, it works:

```
myuser@mypc:~$ . ~/.bashrc
[SUCCESS] Thank you and goodbye.
myuser@mypc:~$ slhelp
SahibLib Core Help
...
```

My question is, **why isn't the script properly executing in ~/.bashrc**?

---

**Update**: Writing some debug commands to `core.sls`, it seems that the file executes *perfectly*. It gets to the end of the file, and returns a standard exit code. This makes the problem even *more* strange, because now it seems that Bash is just ignoring the function definitions outright.
Also, if you need to see `core.sls`, or any of the files, they're available [here](http://github.com/InitializeSahib/SahibLib)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [your link](http://github.com/InitializeSahib/SahibLib), near the bottom of that page, I see this line:

```
echo "/home/myusername/sahiblib/sahibload" >> ~/.bashrc
```

This indicates that, when `~/.bashrc` is run, it will *execute* `sahibload`, *not source it*.  That means that any functions defined by  `sahibload` will be lost when execution of  `sahibload` completes and control is returned to `~/.bashrc`.

If you want functions defined by `sahibload` to survive, use:

```
echo ". /home/myusername/sahiblib/sahibload" >> ~/.bashrc
```

#### Simpler example

Let's consider this test file:

```
$ cat loader
#!/bin/sh
hello() { echo Hello; }
```

Before executing the script, there is no function `hello`:

```
$ hello
bash: hello: command not found
```

After we execute the script, there still is no function named `hello`:

```
$ ./loader
$ hello
bash: hello: command not found
```

In the above, `loader` is executed the same way that `sahibload` is executed in `~/.bashrc`.

Now, let's source `loader` and observe that the definition of `hello` survives:

```
$ . ./loader
$ hello
Hello
```

`sahibload` needs to be sourced, not executed, in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: I bow down to thee, Bash overlord. ;)